# Using write.graph in igraph to output a .net file

Tags: r, igraph

I think I am missing rather simple here, but what is the syntax for adding arguments to the write.graph function in R's igraph package? I am trying to output a network to a pajek formatted file (.net) with weighted edges and IDs. I've tried the following commands, but keep getting errors ("*Unknown arguments to write.graph (Pajek format).*"):

```
write.graph(weightedg,file="musGiant2012.net", format="pajek",'weight')
write.graph(weightedg,file="musGiant2012.net", format="pajek", id=TRUE)
write.graph(weightedg,file="musGiant2012.net", format="pajek", ("id"))
```

Plus many others. I am pretty sure that I am committing a simple syntax error, but cannot find any guidance on how to correct it.

Comment: What are the error messages? They will likely be informative.

Comment: Unknown arguments to write.graph (Pajek format). Same thing every time. That is why I am guessing it's just a syntax problem. I tried adding args= as well, which has not worked.

Comment: This is a total guess, but I'm thinking you need to just set the weights and ids on the graph itself, and then not pass any further arguments beyond `format="pajek"`.

Comment: @thelatemail: it was a very good guess. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs at http://igraph.org/r/doc/write.graph.html:

> The Pajek format is a text file, see read.graph for details. Appropriate vertex and edge attributes are also written to the file. This format has no additional arguments.

And http://igraph.org/r/doc/read.graph.html shows that edge weights are supported, and vertex ids are supported as well. So if you have your vertex ids as an attribute called `id`, and your edge weights as an attribute called `weight`, then you do not need any extra argument. E.g.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.ring(5)
V(g)$id <- letters[1:5]
E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g))

tmp <- tempfile()
write.graph(g, file = tmp, format = "pajek")

cat(readLines(tmp), sep = "\n")

#> *Vertices 5
#> 1 "a"
#> 2 "b"
#> 3 "c"
#> 4 "d"
#> 5 "e"
#> *Edges
#> 1 2 0.054399197222665
#> 2 3 0.503386947326362
#> 3 4 0.373047293629497
#> 4 5 0.84542120853439
#> 1 5 0.610330935101956
```